# Partially update a registry value through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm in the process of creating a script to update some registry values for an app through PowerShell. I have managed to understand each value for almost everything I need to update using ProcMon, however, I can't seem to understand one.

For context, I am looking to enable the mute setting in an application. I have tracked down the registry entry, but it looks like it shares different functions. This is:

Mute disabled is: Type: REG_SZ, Length: 46, Data: 3 156 156 1441 760 0 0
Mute enabled is: Type: REG_SZ, Length: 46, Data: 3 156 156 1441 760 1 0

This is in the 'main window' property.

So, after much testing, it's clear what needs to be edited. But the rest of the string can be different. So I will only need to edit the second last digit, leaving the previous value unchanged.

At this time, the only thing I can come up with for the script is to query the current value, edit the second last digit and then update the whole registry value.

I have multiple servers to do this on.

My question is, is there another way I can find more information on what the other values mean? Or is there a way to update a registry value, but only edit the 'mute' value.

Comment: What is the registry key path? Is that some specific application registry keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only read/write entire registry values. Assuming that the numbers in that string value are separated by spaces you could split the string, modify the second-last element, then join the array back to a string and write it back to the registry.

```
$key = 'HKCU:\...'
$val = 'something'

$s = Get-ItemProperty -Path $key | Select-Object -Expand $val
$a = $s.Split()
$a[-2] = '1'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name $val -Value "$a"
```

Using `"$a"` instead of `$a` (without quotes) causes the array to be mangled into a space-separated string (since the default output field separator defined in the variable `$OFS` is a space).

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's Perfect.